# A way to reduce the number of questions with only images?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, code-formatting

#### The problem:

This is something that I particularly see a lot in the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) tag. People will ask questions that look something like the following:

> I have the following dataframe <link to imgur image of the current
> dataframe>.
>
> I want the dataframe to look like the following <link to imgur image
> of the theoretical dataframe>.
>
> How can I achieve this. If you are lucky I might explain what I even want done beyond just giving images.

A recent [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910602/replacing-values-in-columns-of-similar-rows-with-conditional-value-from-another):

> I have a DataFrame like <\this>.
>
> But I want it to be like <\this>.
>
> So for all rows with the same 'Name' column value, I want 'Tot' to
> have the value from 'Pop' when the 'Group' value is 0.

Now sure one can go to the images, and try to figure it out from there, but if the asker had taken the extra 2 minutes to add the actual dataframe as text in the question (as described in [The Pandas How-To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) it would be a lot easier for us to answer. Switching from images to copyable text also somewhat forces the user to think about if there question is written as a MRE. Since a giant dataframe image doesn't look silly when asking, but a giant amount of text (hopefully) does.

#### The requested feature:

When asking a question with a "terrible" title (ex. "What is this error?") a popup shows that you aren't able to ask a question with that title. Can we have a similar (even if non-binding) pop-up that is triggered for questions that link to imgur but have less than some threshold of code blocks.

#### The two main aspects I think need discussion:

- How far reaching is this issue? Is this only [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) related, or do other tags suffer from similar issues?
- On the popup being "binding" (unable to post): Is there ever a time when you would have images without at least one bit of formatted code?

Comment: Other tags have the same "problem"; many users post images of their sample data for SQL related questions as images which often doesn't help us help them. The best things you can do is the same as always; comment to suggest they supply the sample in a consumable format and/or downvote if the question really isn't helpful due to the images. Users that keep posting images for text will eventually learn, or if their questions are poorly received by the community, get a question ban. The "problem" tends to sort itself out as people they don't provide helpful question, *normally* don't get answers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer for both the askers and the (would be) answerers if this gets addressed at the asking phase rather than the comments phase? More likely to get an answer and easier to answer

Comment: Ban images entirely, close the site down, or exterminate mankind. Those are pretty much the only options. Everyone using an image thinks they really, really REALLY need the image no matter what you do to dissuade them.

Comment: I fail to see how the options are images no matter what or no images at all. There clearly is a middle ground. I even propose a possible middle ground in my question

Comment: It's also somewhat common in the [tag:piet] tag :). what will you do for questions like those?

Comment: Related: [Image-only question shouldn't be accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346422/image-only-question-shouldnt-be-accepted)

Comment: Why does it need code blocks? What if it's a HowTo-Question with an illustration of a problem in a tool?

Comment: A button (or special markdown) for users with 10k+ that gives the OP an electric shock. it would be like *"Welcome to stackoverflow [shock], please read the help on asking a question [shock], images of code are discouraged on stackOverflow [shock] [shock] [shock]"*

Comment: You can link people to: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I realise this isn't a *solution* but it's still something you can do in the meantime.

Comment: @VLAZ or maybe that link can be in the non-binding popup? Then users will have to acknowledge (if they read it) whether or not that link applies to them.

Comment: @VLAZ I have a standard comment with that link and it helps quite often.

Comment: @jps I personally don't like leaving canned comments. However, I've added the link to my profile bio which already lists things I dislike. Makes copying it for a comment much more convenient.

Comment: @00110001 https://i.redd.it/v53przfht6n01.png

Comment: Honestly, these are plain old "gimme da codez". Whether the data is provided as an image or text does not change that they are inherently bad questions.

Comment: @VLAZ as long as it's just the same problem (images of code/data), why not respond with the same canned comment? I don't want to waste more time than the OP spent to throw a LQ question over our fence

Comment: @jps because I personally dislike them. I can see the value but I don't want to use them.

Comment: @VLAZ that's ok.

Comment: Maybe: Do not allow any links or images for first questions of users (for the first day of that question maybe even). If they cannot say it in words, likely they cannot say it at all.

Comment: Is there a way to get notifications on such posts? I'd happily translate worthy questions. I thought the algorithm triggered those posts for moderation because of low text content.

Comment: @BugHunterUK please try not to transcribe questions from images. This introduces a risk of typos or other mistakes. Ultimately, it's the job of the question asker to provide all information for a question to be answered. In the case of images of text, they *already* have the textual information and chose not to share it. We shouldn't encourage behaviour that poses more undue burden on the community. Feel free to improve the questions if the problems are something like typos, bad wording, improper formatting, and similar.

Comment: I am tempted to say downvote, vote to close if appropriate, and move on with life. These painfully inadequate posts are a dime a dozen, and tag notwithstanding I would not lose sleep over this.

Comment: as a side note, imgur is often blocked on corporate environment, which mean you can't even see the images on the post.

Comment: Particularly, the pandas tag appears to me to be one of those tags thats beyond saving with a higher number of low quality questions than average. I'd suggest just adding it to your list of ignore tags before the amount of downvotes you dish out affect your mental health

Comment: @VLAZ roger that, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

While your suggestion is, like most suggestions posted on Meta, both reasonable and simple, the chance of it being implemented within the next millennium is, again like most suggestions, zero or as close to it as it is possible to be. For the simple reason that anything that will decrease the number of questions posted, and therefore the workload on curators, is the exact opposite of what Stack Exchange Inc. wants to see.

All you can do to combat these questions is downvote and vote to close. Don't waste your time doing anything else, even posting a canned comment - it's not your responsibility to hold users' hands, it's their responsibility to inform themselves of the rules and make their questions as answerable as possible.

Comment: "is the exact opposite of what Stack Exchange Inc. wants to see" Are you referring to ad revenue? Or a different reason?

Comment: Just plain impressions/views. Stack Exchange Inc. is controlled by its investors, investors want to see numbers perpetually increasing, even though that is obviously impossible and therefore nonsensical.

Comment: "zero or as close to it as it is possible to be" I think you are looking for an epsilon.

Comment: @IanKemp I am wondering if we know whether the number of views increases with poorly designed questions as someone searching would be drawn to the title, and subsequently rapidly click to look somewhere else.

Comment: @ultradian That is yet another problem with using a metric as simple, one-dimensional, and probably rubbish like views, or even clicks. And yet the multibillion-dollar advertising industry is *built* on this sort of completely unscientific BS. It boggles the mind.

Answer (score 21):

The problem with these questions is not the images: The questions themselves contain no clear, specific problem to solve – they are inherently "gimme codez" regardless of the data being provided properly.

If you want to see fewer questions like these, *stop answering them*. Close-vote if any close reasons apply.*
Strongly consider to downvote them. If you feel kind, add a canned comment to point the asker to the help center.

---

* The usual suspects are "Needs debugging details" if vital information is in images, and "Needs details or clarity" if it is unclear what issue there is in solving the task.

Comment: In my experience: downvoting answers to such utter garbage questions also stops those answering from doing so in the future. Which again reduces the answer rate to said questions and hopefully educates those answering enough to just downvote and close the question and move on.

Comment: @Lino I wholeheartedly disagree with that philosophy.  The tooltip for downvoting an answer says: "This answer is not useful".  That means the vote should reflect the content of the answer, not the content of the question.  If the answer correctly answers the question, then the question was indeed answerable, even if it is low quality.  If the answer does not answer the question because the question is unclear, then the answer itself is "not useful".

Comment: My point is: To judge an answer by the question it is answering is a disservice to the site.  Questions can be edited.  Judge the answer for how it answers the question, and if the question is truly unclear, you should still come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Keep in mind that questions do not just belong to the person asking them – they belong to the entire community. It matters little whether *the OP* can tell if their question was answered. Even if an answer manages to connect input and output, if the largest part of its approach is guesswork which may or may not be valid for similar problems, it is not generally useful.

Comment: @Lino If you have the privilege, consider to just delete such questions when they become eligible. This has a similar effect but involves more of a community vote.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong "*To judge an answer by the question it is answering is a disservice to the site.*" judging an answer as to its service to the site *is* valid.

Comment: My experience, @Lino is the opposite: downvoting a garbage answer is mostly pointless. A single upvote offsets five downvotes. If one or two people downvote a garbage answer, a single upvote will still continue to encourage the answerer to post more garbage answers. They still got a little bit of karma out of the deal. Garbage questions attract garbage answers, and garbage "me-too" upvotes.

Answer (score 13):

Same as with other questions with similar problems: downvote and/or VTC with an applicable reason.

Yes, you can comment with a more specific advice, but if there's a stream of these, you likely can't afford to do that for each one and have to use the streamlined approach.

---

If there is a specific common problem that existing close reasons don't cover, you can suggest to add an new/augment an existing close reason.

Comment: If you feel like helping the user ask a better question next time, post one of the many available "canned" comments, for example see: *Repository of useful pro-forma comments - MSE*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments/136615#136615 .

Comment: "If there is a specific common problem that existing close reasons don't cover, you can suggest to add an new/augment an existing close reason." Thanks for brightening my morning with a good laugh :).

Answer (score 12):

This is also a reasonably big problem when it comes to questions based on [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29).

We need to encourage users not to answer low-effort questions from people who simply post images.

Answer (score 5):

Close vote for "debug information required", without looking at the screenshot. Usually, especially when it's screenshots of error messages, they may hide their duplicate inside of a screenshot, which one has to manually convert to text-form, in order to identify them as dupe.

Machine learning might not be an option, because even if it could detect the content - and then suggest the question it duplicates (as it already is the case, when one asks in text-form). One would need to train a model, which detects text in red and can reasonably read stack-traces. It would also need to know the tabs of the most common IDE. Even if there are tons of sample-material (screenshots), training the model likely could only be IDE (or environment) specific. Volunteers still do a better job and are cheaper - simply because they may have experience.

It still would make moderation easier, if at least the text-form could be extracted... so that one does not manually have to replicate it, in order to determine if it's a duplicate question; I mean, rather assisted and semi-automatic, than full-automatic and possibly running wild.

I'd all be for a new moderation tool: an "extract text" button (so that one could conveniently copy and paste the content provided as screenshot in text-form, just alike the search engine expects it).

Comment: Building an OCR tool with a sufficient degree of accuracy to be actually useful is... not easy. The asker is the one who wants an answer; channel that motivation to eliminate the need for OCR. The first paragraph is *the* answer.

Comment: Well, my concern is merely to choose a misleading close-reason. A predefined reason "screenshots need to be replaced with text-format" would be more speaking. ML is even pretty good at extracting text from screenshots; it wouldn't need to make any sense out of it, but only would have to provide all found text, so that one could copy, paste and flag as duplicate (in a semi-automatic manner).

Comment: @CodyGray I am always hesitant whether "Needs debugging details" is appropriate – these questions do not ask for debugging. There is nothing to debug in the first place.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I feel like the SO close reasons have gotten significantly worse since 2015, and don't clearly match some of the most common actual reasons (gimme teh codez / lack of effort especially on homework questions).  The new text on "too broad" / "needs more focus" is especially bad, making it sound like it's specifically about multiple questions, leaving no close reason that sounds right for questions that are too open-ended and would need a book or chapter to fully answer.  IDK, maybe we're only supposed to downvote but not close, or at least that's what SO corporate wants.