# How did a question holding nothing but a link-text to an image not get blocked while asking?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Take a look at: [not creating the file showing error file not build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359861/not-creating-the-file-showing-error-file-not-build)
There is nothing in the question that is not a link-text (and the link points to a screenshot of the code).
Why do we allow questions of this format? What kind of useful questions can be asked which have this format?
Shouldn't the system request the user to add some text to the question?
I agree that the user might get around it by adding garbage text, but that can be said about almost every filter we have.
I personally think it's time we re-thought the formats which are actually useful in asking questions and enforced those, if not to all, at least to new contributors.

Comment: As to how, there's no filter/rule that blocks this. There is however an old feature-request to not accept those kind of "questions": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346422/2745495

Comment: It sort of goes hand in hand with posting links that don't exist or goes to dead content. Is it worth stressing over? I don't think so. The Users of StackOverflow are quite rapid with closing questions of poor content or content that does not meet forum guidelines. Language is a large barrier for a great number of people that come to StackOverflow for assistance and for many it's easier to post a link or image of code rather than **learn** how to properly post it in a question post. I like to give them credit for trying. It's not easy to learn several languages to ask a question.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Several? I thought mainstream SO was only in English and non-English sites were separate?

Comment: It *is* English only, @kesarlingHe-Him , but that doesn't mean that everyone here who posts as English has their 1st or even 2nd language.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him, Yes...SO is English and yes there are other language variants but what I mean by several is the fact of learning English (other than their native language), learning the programming language they are dealing with and that in itself could be several, and, even though slight, learning the language of how to post a question with code in StackOverflow. I'm sure it can get a little overwhelming for some people that are frustrated towards locating a solution to a question poor instruction just can't seem to or are unwilling to provide. Sometimes we forget where we come from.

Comment: Somewhat related: [an answer to *Upcoming Feature Test: Ask Wizard for New Users*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/upcoming-feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users/416327#416327)

Comment: @DevilsHnd: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) is [not a](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) [forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. You could ask quite the same questions with link text than with bare text, or?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Well excuse my slip of the tongue...."Community".

Comment: @eis, no. That is not what I mean. What I meant was, how did a question with nothing but a link in the body get accepted in the first place. It could as easily have been a plain-text, which is what the last but one line of my post covers.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him but it is not "nothing but a link". it has a link text too, which informationwise can hold exactly the same information as plain text.

Comment: if the post contents would have been `https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmNCK.png` only, then I would understand your claim.